# CSS not applying to a Web Part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css, content-editor-web-part

I have several web parts on a page, 2 of them are CEWPs.

1 links to the CSS and 1 links to a text file.

The CSS is applied to all other web parts on the page but it will not apply to the CEWP linking to a text file.

However, when I go to edit the page the CSS then applies!

This is what I am trying to apply to the offending WP. The same code (changing the WPQ numbers, works on all other web parts)

```
.s4-wpcell#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6
.ms-webpart-titleText { font-size:30px; background-color:#924473 ; }
.s4-wpcell#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6 { background-color:#4b293d ; }
    #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6 .ms-vb2
    {
        color:#ffffff ;
        font-size: 12pt ;
    }
    #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6 .ms-vb-user A
    {
        color:#ffffff ;
        font-size: 12pt ;
    }
```

Comment: you can try to add "! important" to enforce the style...

Comment: tried that. makes no difference on any line. :-)

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Please add the tag for that!

Comment: 2013 Enterprise - tags added!

Comment: did you add style tags in text file? you dont have to add that in css file but you have add that in text file

Comment: but wont adding style tags in the text file only alter the text in the file, rather than the font size and background of the title of the web part?

Comment: How did you reference the css to the page. Reference to a css file or `<style>` tags directly on the page?

Comment: I have a css file (in a folder called CSS, in Site Assets) that is linked to on that page via a CEWP.